# Why do you guys downvote ;

Tags: discussion, down-votes

We should use platforms like this to spread the deen; it's not about Islam StackExchange guidelines.

Answer for the Sake of Allah; Is it for reputation?

Some people speak like they put StackExchange before Islam; what are you here for ?

Start an answer by saying Assalamualykum ; one guy is downvoting because i didn't put "" I assume .

I fell like it's just the same people who downvote

Get out of this mindset & remember that we are brothers; the bond between brothers as muslim is stronger than blood bonds. We talk as brothers, Islam StackExchange is not like the others since we are brothers.

Someone will probably Google it and find the question I asked; even though it's not a common question

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, I personally disagree with the voting system. I have seen many times that questions come through and they are downvoted. People are coming from all walks of life and need answers instead of rejection. 100% agreed that we are all Muslims. Yes there are different sects but our goal should be to unite all of us under one group with wisdom, patience and beauty. Instead of downvoting it should be up to the person questioning to decide which answer they deem best. You can have people upvote an answer and might not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't check a user's credentials at the door.

Your claim that "we are brothers" is a lovely ideal, but it's optimistic at best: There's over twenty-five thousand users on Islam Stack Exchange, and quite frankly we have absolutely no idea how many of them are practicing Muslims, much less how qualified any of them are at answering questions.

Every single one of these people can ask and answer questions, and here that means questions about Islam, about the deen that you hold so dearly. Some of them could be imparting valuable knowledge, some could be spreading misinformation out of ignorance, or even others telling outright lies out of malice. Such is the nature of the Internet.

You are correct when you say Islam Stack Exchange is not like the other Stack Exchange sites: We have little in common with most of the Stack Exchange network which focuses on more technically-oriented topics. The closest site to ours is probably [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com) which, quite frankly, has far stricter rules, stronger enforcement, and does a lot more downvoting than we do.

Our voting system is a major reason that people trust Stack Exchange to answer their questions on any number of topics: The people who ask probably don't have the knowledge and skills to recognize honest and useful answers from misinformation and lies. I find this especially the case here, many of the questions we receive show little to no understanding of Islamic fundamentals or  the study of fiqh.

Voting is how we, the community, curate the information that is posted. It's a form of peer review, since the people who are best qualified to recognize valuable and useful information are the people who have expertise in the topic, in this case the topic of Islam. Users who earn a lot of reputation do so because the community has recognized the value of their posts; those users in turn are granted increased curating powers to help ensure that useful answers are promoted over less useful ones.

Downvotes are supposed to be a criticism of the post, not the user: They are not necessarily telling you that your post is *wrong*, so much as it's telling you that your post is not *useful*. What makes a post "useful" varies widely depending on the question and what information they're seeking, not only for the questionasker themselves but for anyone who might be searching for answers to that same question in the future.

Instead of taking downvotes personally, look at it as an opportunity to improve. The more useful your posts are — the more useful the community *sees* them — the more it will help you spread the deen.

Comment: There was  no need to do all this. I asked about penguins being halal; they just downvote,

Comment: if they say it's halal ; end of the story , at least someone who has same question will google and find my post

Comment: @AamirshahSHAIK If you want critique about an existing question, ask a separate question about that on Islam Meta. This question was a general question about why people downvote, which is what I answered.

Comment: Masha Allah, great answer ☺️